# Best way to go about testing 1000 case creations in a day - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to know the best way to go about creating 1000 "cases" on a platform in a day using Jmeter and testing the throughput.

Currently I am thinking of using Ultimate thread group for "hold load for, sec = 28800" (8 Hours).
We should have about 100 users on our platform at any given moment creating these cases.

What would be the best way to test this? I would like to run the test for the full 8 hours over night and not burst test it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve it with normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configured like:

[image]

This way your test will stop either after creating 1000 cases or after 8 hours pass (whatever comes the first)

If you want to limit case creation rate to 1000 cases in 8 hours which gives 125 cases per hour which means that 1 user will create 5 cases in 4 hours you can limit the rate of Samplers execution using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

Comment: Great, thank you! And if I wanted to limit the case creation time to 15 minutes per a user?

Comment: If you want to end creation without waiting it to complete after 15 minutes - put it under [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) or remove/adjust the [Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) which slow JMeter down.